# No bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, xetex, biber

Please help me. This is my final part of my work, and this happens. I am not an expert in LaTeX, but I prefer to use it.

I check all my document and some compatibilities with fonts and csquotes, but it doesn't generate any reference, neither the title of the section of the bibliography.

I am using XeLaTex and Biber, and the software which I used is Texpad, I also ran in Texshop; but nothing.

This is part of the `log`:

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/xelatex -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -output-directory=/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp Tarea01_3.tex

This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Tarea01_3.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
 ...
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document has been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}).

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/spanish.lbx) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty) (/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.bbl) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'hennessey2006' on page 1 undefined on input line 505.

[1]

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 575.

[2] (/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                Tarea01_3
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
Output written on /Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.pdf (2 pages).
SyncTeX written on /Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.log.


/Library/TeX/texbin/biber /Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.bcf

INFO - This is Biber 2.16
INFO - Logfile is '/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.blg'
INFO - Reading '/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'biblio.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source '/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/msc/biblio.bib'
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'hennessey2006' (section 0)
INFO - Overriding locale 'es-ES' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Overriding locale 'es-ES' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'nty' and locale 'es-ES'
INFO - Writing '/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to /Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.bbl
INFO - WARNINGS: 1


/Library/TeX/texbin/xelatex -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -output-directory=/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp Tarea01_3.tex

This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Tarea01_3.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
 ....
Writing index file Tarea01_3.idx
...
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document has been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}).

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/spanish.lbx) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty) (/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.bbl) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'hennessey2006' on page 1 undefined on input line 505.

[1]

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 575.

[2] (/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                Tarea01_3
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
Output written on /Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.pdf (2 pages).
SyncTeX written on /Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.log.


/Library/TeX/texbin/xelatex -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -output-directory=/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp Tarea01_3.tex

This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Tarea01_3.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
....
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document has been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}).

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/spanish.lbx) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty) (/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.bbl) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'hennessey2006' on page 1 undefined on input line 505.

[1]

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 575.

[2] (/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                Tarea01_3
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
Output written on /Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.pdf (2 pages).
SyncTeX written on /Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.log.


/Library/TeX/texbin/xelatex -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -output-directory=/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp Tarea01_3.tex

This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Tarea01_3.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
....
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document has been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}).

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/spanish.lbx) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty) (/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.bbl) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'hennessey2006' on page 1 undefined on input line 505.

[1]

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 575.

[2] (/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                Tarea01_3
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
Output written on /Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.pdf (2 pages).
SyncTeX written on /Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.log.


/Library/TeX/texbin/xelatex -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -output-directory=/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp Tarea01_3.tex

This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Tarea01_3.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class

....
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document has been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}).

....

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'hennessey2006' on page 1 undefined on input line 505.

[1]

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 575.

[2] (/Users/Isai/Documents/Maestria PUCP/1CIV08 Mecanica/TA-01-20210414/Tarea01/.texpadtmp/Tarea01_3.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                Tarea01_3
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards
```

This is my document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm, top=4cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization.formats.functions}

%\usetikzlibrary{perspective} 

\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\usepackage{layout}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
%\usepackage{tocstyle}
%   \usetocstyle{KOMAlike}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode = symbol}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

Some text \cite{hennessey2006}.

\newpage

\printbibliography

\newpage

\section{Anexos}

\subsection{Problema 04}

Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run the normal cycle `xelatex >bibber (or bibtex) >xelatex (twice)`?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, I ran in Texshop as you comment. Is it fine for you?

Comment: It's fine. Just in case, add `\nocite {*}`  in your preamble. I forgot: what does the .blg file say?

Comment: The only suspicious thing in the log output shown so far is `WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'hennessey2006' (section 0)`. Are you sure you spelled `hennessey2006` correctly? Are you sure that the `biblio.bib` Biber finds is the `.bib` file you think it should find. For more help we'd have to see the full `.log` file of the LaTeX run *after* the Biber run.

Comment: @moewe Maybe something is wrong with Texpad, I am using Texshop now, everything is fine.

Comment: Oh, yeah right. Looking at the `.blg` more closely shows that the Biber run started by Texpad finds `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/msc/biblio.bib`, which is probably not your actual `biblio.bib`. You could probably fix this by supplying the absolute file path to `\addbibresource`. But that is a not-so-pretty workaround for an odd behaviour of your editor (Texpad).

Comment: Texpad has problem in the access for cloud folders from Apple. I've change the location, and now it is fine.

Comment: This looks like an interesting observation that might be helpful for other people as well. Please write up a quick answer (if possible with slightly more detail about your setup) and accept it to show that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would be helping for people who use Texpad from Valleta Ventures.

Texpad has problems about accessing folders and files, something about sand boxing. I don't understand so much about it.

I have all my documents in iCloud Drive, and I think that is the problem. As moewe said, a solution for my problem it would have been supplying the absolute path of my `bib` file, but it wasn't.

So, I change my files location to Desktop, and with the absolute file path, everything goes fine.